# cakephp2x email subject line length

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to send an email using CakePHP 2x utility CakeEmail, I am getting all my values dynamically as below-

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from($from_id);
$Email->to($to_id);
$Email->subject($subject);
$Email->send($body);
```

Sometimes email is sending without any failure, but sometimes it wont. Finally I found the issue with the subject line length. Whenever my subject line is getting bigger then the email is not sending properly through programmatically. But, whenever my subject is line is less than nearly 75 characters then its working perfectly. So, how can I fix this issue by enlarging subject line length. Normally in gmail there is no restriction of subject length. But programmatically it is not allowing in CakePHP 2x CakeEmail utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by myself. Simply change the core behavior of Email functionality in Cake Lib. Open \lib\Cake\Network\Email\MailTransport.php and edit line no - 47 as below

```
$this->_mail($to, str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $email->subject()), $message, $headers, $params);
```

So, the basic change is to remove "New Line" & "Carriage Return" from Subject text. Whenever our subject text becomes more than 75 characters, framework will automatically put new line in the subject text, which wont work while on sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use SMTP. If not then please send mail using SMTP. and the check.
Please follow the given link bellow.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

Comment: Can't be possible without using SMTP. Because without SMTP configuration also mail functionality is working in server. The only problem is with the subject line length.

Comment: You can use Php mailer component in cakephp and then check.what happen?